# Equal spacing in all the strings of the columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have more than 1.400.000 rows of data in an Address column.

```
3, clive row, calcutta
3 , clive row,calcutta
3,clive row , calcutta
```

Spacing between the strings are uneven and I want all of them in the same format as below:

```
3, clive row, calcutta
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to replace any spaces before & after a comma and comma itself with `", "`:

```
df.Address = df.Address.str.replace(r"\s*,\s*", ", ", regex=True)
```

another way is to split over possible spaces before & after comma and comma itself and then join with `", "`:

```
df.Address = df.Address.str.split(r"\s*,\s*").str.join(", ")
```

to get

```
>>> df.Address

0    3, clive row, calcutta
1    3, clive row, calcutta
2    3, clive row, calcutta
Name: Address, dtype: object
```